# removing all view controllers completly from tabbar controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to remove all view controllers completly from tabbar controller whether it consists or not, and to add new view controllers
into tababr controller at run time?is it possible to do it?I have done as folowing , it is not giving output?

```
 UIViewController *thisIsTheViewControllerIWantToSetNow; 
 int indexForViewControllerYouWantToReplace;  
 NSMutableArray *tabbarViewControllers = [self. tabController.viewControllers mutableCopy]; 
  [tabbarViewControllers removeAllObjects];



 self.tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.moreNavController, self.logInNavController, nil];;
```

Comment: What is `self` in this example, where is its `tabbar` property defined, and what value does the `tabbar` property contain when the above code is run?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `self` in the example given is an instance of `UITabBarController` then trying to manipulate its `tabbar` directly is not appropriate. Instead set the `viewControllers` property.
As the `UITabBarController` docs state:

> tabBar The tab bar view associated with this controller. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic,readonly) UITabBar *tabBar
>
> Discussion
>
> You should
>   never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself stored in this
>   property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view throws an
>   exception. To configure the items for your tab bar interface, you
>   should instead assign one or more custom view controllers to the
>   viewControllers property. The tab bar collects the needed tab bar
>   items from the view controllers you specify.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW4

Comment: I did not understand,i tried in appdelegate.m file
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITabBarController *tabController; it is not working….

Comment: What is not working? What are you trying to accomplish? What did you try? What unexpected result did you see? Don't ask me to guess what "not working" means.

You'll need a reference to the tab bar controller being displayed and to the view controllers you want it to display instead of its current contents. Do you have either of those?
You'll also need to decide which object is responsible for changing the tab bar controller's contents. Is that the app delegate?